# If you get once vaccinated against tetanus, will you get protected eternally?

Tags: tetanus-shot

I heard a claim that if one has got a tetanus vaccine in the past, the history of medicine does not know any case where vaccinated person has got a tetanus. Is that true and is there any publication for this claim?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: You may have misunderstood; it's commonly thought that if one has received a **full 3-dose primary tetanus vaccination series**, getting tetanus is highly unlikely, however I've never seen proof. Serological studies clearly demonstrate waning immunity years after immunization, and I once (only ever once!) admitted an adult in his late 20s who had a full primary series but had gotten a tetanus prone injury and presented with painful muscle spasticity and rigidity. So no, it's not true.

Answer (score 3):

One vaccination alone will not protect you for life, but **as for the childhood vaccination programs**:

### The recommendations depend on your country.

In the US, adults need 1 booster shot of the Td vaccine (a type of vaccine which protects preteens, teens, and adults from tetanus and diphtheria) every 10 years as part of their routine vaccine schedule (for more on that, see the [Tetanus (Lockjaw)](https://www.hhs.gov/immunization/diseases/tetanus/index.html) page from the U.S. Department of Health & Human Services). If you get a deep cut or a burn, you may need the booster earlier — especially if the cut or burn is dirty.

> If you missed the Tdap booster as a teen, you’ll need to get a Tdap booster instead to make sure you have protection from whooping cough.

If you are in the UK, a total of 5 doses of tetanus vaccine are recommended for life (see the [NHS Tetanus](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/tetanus/) page for more).

> The tetanus vaccine is given as part of the NHS childhood vaccination programme.
>
> The full course of vaccination includes 5 injections, usually given on the following schedule:
>
> - the first 3 doses are given as part of the 6-in-1 vaccine at age 8, 12 and 16 weeks
> - a booster dose is given as part of the 4-in-1 pre-school booster at age 3 years and 4 months
> - a final dose is given as part of the 3-in-1 teenage booster at age 14
>
> This course of 5 injections should provide long-lasting protection against tetanus. However, if you or your child has a deep or dirty wound, it's best to get medical advice.
>
> If you're not sure whether you've had the full vaccination course, contact your GP surgery for advice. It's possible to fully vaccinate older children and adults who were not vaccinated when they were younger.

The same page also states that if you're planning to travel abroad and have not been fully vaccinated against tetanus, or you're going to an area with limited medical facilities and your last vaccine dose was more than 10 years ago, contact your GP surgery for advice.

> You'll be offered the 3-in-1 teenage booster. This injection, which also protects against diphtheria and polio, is usually free on the NHS.

Comment: Not that I would argue with a well-supported answer, but does this answer the question asked?

Comment: Yes, @anongoodnurse, directly.  The question is, will you have lifetime protection (eternally). My answer is that according to national medical and Government advice, it depends on your country.